# So how is `ROLLBACK` in Oracle exception handler different from my `ROLLBACK`?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, rollback, oracleexception

How Oracle Database rollback to the beginning of the PL/SQL block, but not the earlier DML instructions (I think all this come under one single transaction).  Because when I try to `ROLLBACK` creating an exception handler all the instructions until last `COMMIT` are rolled back.

```
create table mytable (num int not null primary key);

insert into mytable values(1); // My ROLLBACK, rollbacks to here.

begin       // Oracle exception handler rollbacks to here.
insert into mytable values(3);
  begin
   insert into mytable values(2);
   insert into mytable values(1);
  end;
  /* Incase I  try to ROLLBACK all the updates including the first insert is gone.*/
  --exception when dup_val_on_index then
  --rollback;
end;
```

Final table data:
1) Incase of oracle handling exception

```
mytable 
_______
1
```

2) Incase of oracle handling exception

```
mytable 
_______
```

So how is `ROLLBACK` in Oracle exception handler different from my `ROLLBACK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Oracle works. Your first INSERT was done correctly (i.e. inserted "1" into a table).

Then you ran an anonymous PL/SQL block which inserts "3", then "2", and fails when trying to insert "1" due to primary key violation.

If unhandled exception occurs during execution of that PL/SQL block (which is what you say that "Oracle exception handler rollbacks to here"), Oracle rolls back to the beginning of the PL/SQL block.

When you utilize EXCEPTION handler and issue ROLLBACK, then it is YOU who decide what to do if something happens, and that is to revert all changes to previous COMMIT which was an implicitly done COMMIT after executing the CREATE TABLE statement, so following INSERT "1" is also rolled back.

Comment: What logic or how exactly does "Oracle rolls back to the beginning of the PL/SQL block". I mean it is not like rollback to last commit or rollback to particular save point

Comment: That is an *implicit rollback*; have a look at this document: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#i7105, search for "How Oracle Does Implicit Rollbacks".

Answer (score 0):

considering any DML statement as an atomic transaction , you are grouping in BEGIN ... END several statements as an atomic transaction and the exception inside will cause the statements in this block to be rolled back.
Use SAVEPOINT to better handle rollback scenario.

Comment: The DML is not atomic transaction, if so why would my `rollback` undoes it.

Comment: @sql_dummy in effect it is. You can think of the whole anonymous block as behaving like a single DML statement. If it fails, it rolls back to its own start, just like an update etc.