# Document error? Subprogram with an unhandled exception does not do any rollback?

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, rollback, unhandled-exception

Is following statement from [doc:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#i7105) valid?

> If you exit a stored subprogram with an unhandled exception, PL/SQL
>   does not assign values to OUT parameters, and does not do any rollback

As per the statement `ROLLBACK` should not happen when my stored procedure `testy` raise an exception unhandled. And as per document insert 3, insert 2 should be successful, but no insert are successful.

```
create table mytable (num int not null primary key);

insert into mytable values(1);

create or replace procedure testy is
begin
insert into mytable values(2);
insert into mytable values(1); //throws error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SRISRI1.SYS_C0011447) violated
end;

create or replace procedure testp is
begin
insert into mytable values(3);
testy;
insert into mytable values(4);
end;

exec testp; 

select * from mytable;

mytable
_______
1
```

Answer (score 0):

We've discussed it in your [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079311/so-how-is-rollback-in-oracle-exception-handler-different-from-my-rollback/48081815#48081815), haven't we?

William Robertson said:

> You can think of the whole anonymous block as behaving like a single
>   DML statement. If it fails, it rolls back to its own start, just like
>   an update etc.

- you inserted value "1" via INSERT INTO statement
- then you called TESTP which

  - inserted "3"
  - called TESTY which
  - inserted "2"
  - tried to insert "1" but failed

Oracle performed an *implicit rollback* and reverted INSERT 2 and INSERT 3, which returns you back to the starting point, i.e. to a situation you've had before executing the TESTP procedure, and that is *value 1 in the table*.

Comment: no, I mean here my question is different. As per doc "does not do any rollback"  in case of "stored subprogram with an unhandled exception". But there is roll back performed in actual.

Comment: Not *explicitly*, but - it wouldn't do any harm if you actually read what you see. Oracle performed an *implicit* rollback as PL/SQL block failed.

Comment: All the handling performed by Oracle would be called as implicit right? If not  how is Oracle explicitly handling any different?

Comment: It is you (a developer) who *explicitly* does something. For example, when you run ALTER TABLE statement, Oracle will *implicitly* commit any previous changes. When you INSERT INTO, UPDATE and DELETE and COMMIT at the end, then you *explicitly* ordered Oracle to save changes, i.e. *commit*.

Comment: okay but oracle does not do any rollback in this case, neither did I. Then why are these rolled back;

Comment: How do you mean, Oracle doesn't rollback? It does, as soon as you hit a TESTY's INSERT INTO statement that tries to insert yet another "1" into a column constrained by primary key constraint.

Comment: I got the sol [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666826/pl-sql-contradiction-in-oracle-document-on-implicit-rollbacks?rq=1)

Comment: What it says if you call the procedure(raising exception (unhandled)) in anonymous block and catch exception (without applying rollback). The other inserts are not rolled back. So that break downs if exception left unhandled no rollback at the procedure but the roll back happens at anonymous block